# How to listen to children length changes in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I have a code:

```
const container = useRef();
const [items, setItems] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
  setItems(container.current.children.length);
},[container.current, container.current.children.length])

return(
<div ref={container}>
  {
  children.map(item => <Item/>)
  }
</div>
)
```

`items.length !== children.length` so I want to listen to `container.current.children.length` size and when it changes, change `items` accordingly. But I get error that `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')` I understand why it's happening, but I don't know how to work around it.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959016/react-useref-null-cannot-read-property-children-of-null) help to solve your issue ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to retrieve this information via a ref, when you could get it from `children` directly?

Comment: Because in my case, children won't change. But children themselves could disappear from container based on different conditions. That's why amount of really available items would be constantly changing and it won't be equal to amount of children that were originally passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never put a useRef value inside a depedency array, as it won't trigger the useEffect callback to run if the value has changed.

You have two options here:

1. Create a custom component in which you can manually observe the children length.

```
function ChildrenObserver({ children }) {
  const lastCount = useRef(getChildrenCount());
  const currentCount = getChildrenCount();

  function getChildrenCount() {
    return React.Children.toArray(children).length;
  }

  if (lastCount.current !== currentCount) {
    lastCount.current = currentCount;
    console.log("Children length changed to", lastCount.current);
  }

  return children;
}

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setItems((i) => i + 1)}>Add child</button>
      <ol>
        <ChildrenObserver>
          {Array.from({ length: items }).map((item) => (
            <li key={item}>Item {item}</li>
          ))}
        </ChildrenObserver>
      </ol>
    </>
  );
}
```

2. Create a MutationObserver that listens for dom changes.

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(0);

  const setRef = useCallback((ref) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
      for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === "childList") {
          console.log("Children length changed to", ref.children.length);
        }
      }
    });

    observer.observe(ref, { childList: true });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setItems((i) => i + 1)}>Add child</button>
      <ol ref={setRef}>
        {Array.from({ length: items }).map((item) => (
          <li key={item}>Item {item}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </>
  );
}
```